# Store different values to localStorage from clipboard by clicking button

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have a simple project with some comboboxes that set values to localStorage (39 comboboxes)
i figured out a way to copy whole localStorage to clipboard

```
// копирование всего localStorage в буфер обмена
async function copyJson() {
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      JSON.stringify(localStorage)
    );
      console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
      /* Resolved - text copied to clipboard successfully */
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
    /* Rejected - text failed to copy to the clipboard */
  }
}
```

Then i'm able to clear local storage:

```
// полная очистка localStorage
function clearJson() {
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

Now that's clear, i need to paste data from clipboard, which could look like this:

```
  {"postval":"Пусто","kuzval1":"Пусто","kuzparkval11":"Пусто"}
```

I tried to use this code:

```
// вставка localStorage (В разработке!)
var raw = navigator.clipboard.readText(JSON.stringify())
// This will check if raw is valid JSON
async function loadJson(){
try {
  localStorage.setItem(raw,raw);
}
catch (e) {
  // show error to user
}
}
```

But instead of pasting values and keys, all it stores is this:

```
{"[object Promise]":"[object Promise]"}
```

How can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`readText` already returns you a string so you don't need to stringify.
And [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) can only set 1 string key at once so you need to iterate through your data and set 1 by 1.

```js
// вставка localStorage (В разработке!)
var raw = navigator.clipboard.readText()
// This will check if raw is valid JSON
async function loadJson(){
  const storageData = JSON.parse(raw)
  try {
    for (const key in storageData) {
     
      localStorage.setItem(key, storageData[key]);
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    // show error to user
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```